# Get the previous event action in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I'm trying to get the previous event action by using jquery

```
<tr id="det"><td></td></tr>
<tr id="moredet"><td></td></tr>
<tr id="det"><td></td></tr>
```

```
$(document).on("click","#det",function(e){
    $(this).next("#moredet").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

what i want is when row of id "det" is clicked then the next of clicked row of id "moredet" will become fade and when i clicked any other row of id "det" then the previous fadein row will fadeout and next row of id "moredet" of clicked row will fadein.

Comment: You should not have duplicate `id` in a document.

Comment: Yes, use classes instead of ids . Your code seems correct otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use duplicate id use class.Its rule violation. You can use `next` and `prev` with `size` to check condition  to solve your problem.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".det", function(e) {
  if ($(this).next('tr').size() > 0) {
    $(this).next(".moredet").fadeToggle("slow");
  } else {
    $(this).prev(".moredet").fadeToggle("slow");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="det">
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="moredet">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="det">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Sorry to forget the rule i am just a beginner

Comment: Glad to help. Happy Coding :)